# How to extract a tar file compressed multiple times over

Tags: linux, tar

Due to some runaway poor scripting some files meant to be archived were compressed five or six times over. So there are files like this:

```
a_log_file_0.log.1.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz
```

Please how can I fix problematic files like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to un-tar all the levels of tar that have been applied to your file. *If* your file has been created by something like

```
tar czf a_log_file_0.log.1.tar.gz a_log_file_0.log.1
tar czf a_log_file_0.log.1.tar.gz.tar.gz a_log_file_0.log.1.tar.gz
...
```

you can un-tar it step by step like so:

```
tar xzf a_log_file_0.log.1.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz
tar xzf a_log_file_0.log.1.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz
tar xzf a_log_file_0.log.1.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz
---
```

You may want to make sure, that the tar.gz files don't contain other stuff which would ruin your system being un-`tar`ed to the wrong place, maybe overwriting important data.

You may want to make sure that you have enough disk space where you extract multiple levels of tar-ed files.

you may want to remove the intermediate extracted versions of your files.

*If* you have done that by hand for several such tar files and only *if* you are sure that there is only one file in each gzip-ed tar archive, you may want to automate the multi level extraction like this:

```
file=a_log_file_0.log.1.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz
cp $file /tmp/
cd /tmp/
while echo $file | grep -n \\.tar\\..gz
do
  zfile=${file%.tar.gz}
  tar xzf $file
  rm $file
  file=$zfile;
done
```

If names are unexpectedly different from the names in this short scropt, it will not work - intentionally, because the multiple tar archive structure is not the way it is expected.

Have fun extracting!

Comment: You could get rid of intermediates by piping one tar into the other to avoid having to cleanup after each untar